# SNT (Status) in Mist wallet?

Tags: mist, status-im

Can I use my Mist ETH address to receive SNT? And if so, how can I see SNT in my Mist wallet? When I bought Bancor I had to add a Bancor address to watch the token in order to see/access my Bancor balance, yet I can't find an SNT address to use to watch the token.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes - Your personal Mist ETH address is fine (since ETH is an ERC20 token. On the other hand don't do the same for exchanges, e.g. Bittrex generates a separate address for SNT).

Add up the below contract address as you did for BNT; Mist should be able to pull up the default settings for SNT:

0x744d70fdbe2ba4cf95131626614a1763df805b9e